# Make a string in SAS from one column

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have a dataset in SAS and I want to Convert one column into string by the Product. I have attached the image of input and output required.
I need the Colomn STRING in the outut. can anyone please help me ?

[image]

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.  What have you tried ? What errors or unexpected output did you get ?

Comment: @Richard I tried with RETAIN function but it was not working as expected. Next time, I will provide the code as well for the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my quick solution.

> ```
> data temp;
>   length cat $20.;
>   do until (last.prod);
>     set have;
>     by prod notsorted;
>    cat=catx(',',cat,value);
>   end;
>
>   drop value date;
> run;
>
> proc sql;
>   create table want as
>   select have.*, cat as string
>   from have inner join temp
>   on have.prod=temp.prod;
> quit;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I have coded a data step to create the input data:

```
data have;
   input products $
         dates
         value
   ;

   datalines;
a 1 0
a 2 0
a 3 1
a 4 0
a 5 1
a 6 1
b 1 0
b 2 1
b 3 1
b 4 1
b 5 0
b 6 0
c 1 1
c 2 0
c 3 1
c 4 1
c 5 0
c 6 1
;
```

Does the following suggested solution give you what you want?:

```
data want;
   length string $ 20;

   do until(last.products);
      set have;
      by products;

      string = catx(',',string,value);
   end;

   do until(last.products);
      set have;
      by products;

      output;
   end;
run;
```